# pandas dataframe to_html formatters - can't display image

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, email, formatter

Im trying to add an up and down arrow to a pandas data frame with to_html for an email report.

I'm using a lambda function to input an up and down arrow onto column values in my data frame, I know the image html works ok becasue I can put it in the body of the email and it works fine but when I use this function and the pandas formatter it outputs like in the below image (ps. i know the CID is different to whats in my function, I was just tesing something)

Any one have any idea why? Or anyone have a better way to do it?

[image: pandas formatter error]

call:

```
worst_20_accounts.to_html(index=False,formatters={'Last Run Rank Difference': lambda x: check_html_val_for_arrow(x)}))
```

function:

```
def check_html_val_for_arrow(x):
    try:
        if x > 0:
            return str(x) + ' <img src="cid:image7">'
        elif x < 0:
            return str(x) + ' <img src="cid:image8">'
        else:
            return str(x)
    except:
        return str(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `escape=False`

By default, the `pandas.DataFrame.to_html` method escapes any html in the dataframe's values.

```
my_img_snippet = (
    "<img src='https://www.pnglot.com/pngfile/detail/"
    "208-2086079_right-green-arrow-right-green-png-arrow.png'>"
)
df =  pd.DataFrame([[my_img_snippet]])
```

Then

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

[image]

---

#### `style`

You can let the `styler` object handle the rendering

```
df.style
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much